# Resizing Image for TipKit's Tip with UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been trying to implement TipKit on my UIKit-based app and trying to resize the image but seems like there is no way resizing it.

```
var image: Image? {
    return Image("tip-new-project", bundle: nil)
}
```

Tip protocol expects this as Image so I can use resizable modifier but then when I try to use one more modifier to change it's frame, it'll return as View and will get an error.

I also try using smaller image from assets and it still stretches so wondering if anyone have the same issue and find a solution?

Comment: Struggling with the same issue here!